# I don't know if it's a Dahlia plant?

Tags: identification, dahlias

About a month back I planted some dahlia and marigold seeds in a pot. It seemed unsuccessful till this sprout came up.

However, I'm not sure if it's actually something I grew or worth keeping.

Thoughts anyone?

[image: Seedling]

Answer (score 1):

Seedlings are difficult to identify, but that certainly could be a dahlia. At least, I don't see anything that would rule it out. The general shape of the leaf is right, and so are the teeth along the edge. If it is a dahlia, when it grows new leaves, the leaf veins should become more indented on the newer foliage.

Here you can see some dahlia seedlings:

[image]
[image source](http://gardenhow.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-grow-dahlias-from-seed_14.html)

Compare them to the foliage of this mature dahlia plant:

[image] [image source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dahlia)

Notice that the mature leaves have more serrations, and the texture of the leaf is less spongy-looking and more thin, glossy and with slightly indented veins. Also, the mature leaves are compound.

I would suggest letting your seedling grow, and watch for it to develop normal dahlia leaf characteristics. As long as it does, I would assume it's a dahlia until it blooms and proves the case one way or the other.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, it was really helpful and reassuring that I was not growing some random weed. I will look out and keep in mind the for the details as the plant grows. Honestly I don't know what a dahlia seedling is supposed to look like as this is my first attempt growing it from scratch and so far the internet has been my go-to reference 

Comment: @Shaz It still might be a random weed. That's the fun of growing plants from seed. If you haven't grown that plant before, you won't really know until it blooms if it's the plant you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Well it does not look like any of the three plants commonly known as marigold - it could well be a dahlia, but I'm surprised it has started growing at this time of year if you have this outdoors, unless you live somewhere warm.

Comment: Yes I was surprised that to see a sprout as I've had horrid luck with planting flower seeds but since I've seen baby marigold shoots before I assumed they would either have to be a dahlia or some sort of seed based weed which blew into my pot from the way the leaves shot up. I actually do live in a tropical climate and it's at the peak of the heat wave weather currently.